# Detect if executable file is on user's PATH

Tags: bash

In a bash script, I need to determine whether an executable named `foo` is on the PATH.

Comment: This is a duplicate of stackoverflow.com/a/677212, which has much more complete answers.

Comment: ........ why is this feature not in posix

Comment: That existing question is not asking if the executable is on the users PATH.. it just asks if the program exists? So, I find this question. Not the "duplicate".

Comment: Just use `builtin hash` for the job.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `which`:

```
 path_to_executable=$(which name_of_executable)
 if [ -x "$path_to_executable" ] ; then
    echo "It's here: $path_to_executable"
 fi
```

Comment: The check for executable mode flag is redundant. `which` only returns executable files (including scripts)

Comment: The point of the executable check is to make sure that the result of which was the executable, and not an error message.

Comment: Ok, I get it. `if [ -n "$path_to_executable" ]` would have made that clearer (and more efficient)

Comment: which should be avoided, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212

Comment: which is actually a **bad** choice. Rather use the builtin alternative. (See trevor's answer)
Also, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Comment: If you follow the link in the `which should be avoided` comment, you are encouraged to use `command -v` instead. For why that is a non-answer for this question, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53798785/5353461).

Answer (score 54):

You could also use the Bash builtin `type -P`:

```
help type

cmd=ls
[[ $(type -P "$cmd") ]] && echo "$cmd is in PATH"  || 
    { echo "$cmd is NOT in PATH" 1>&2; exit 1; }
```

Comment: can simplify: `type -P "$cmd" && echo "in path" || echo "not in path"`

Comment: Since he didn't specify bash, better to avoid bashisms http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212

Comment: Bash was most certainly specified in the question: "In a bash script…"

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just do this: `type -P " $cmd" > /dev/null && echo "yay"` or `if type -P "$cmd" > /dev/null; then` instead of using a subshell and wrapping the command in `[[ ]]`?

Comment: @Hubro you're correct on a wasted `fork()` and test. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53798785/5353461) for an explanation of `-P` and a more efficient, reusable function which works in both `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: @JamesBroadhead about "avoid bashims". I disagree. See: https://github.com/guettli/programming-guidelines#portable-shell-scripts

Answer (score 26):

### TL;DR:

In `bash`:

```
function is_bin_in_path {
  builtin type -P "$1" &> /dev/null
}
```

Example usage of `is_bin_in_path`:

```
% is_bin_in_path ls && echo "found in path" || echo "not in path"
found in path
```

In `zsh`:

Use `whence -p`  instead.

---

For a version that works in both `{ba,z}sh`:

```sh
# True if $1 is an executable in $PATH
# Works in both {ba,z}sh
function is_bin_in_path {
  if [[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]]; then
    builtin whence -p "$1" &> /dev/null
  else  # bash:
    builtin type -P "$1" &> /dev/null
  fi
}
```

To test that ALL given commands are executables in $PATH:

```sh
# True iff all arguments are executable in $PATH
function is_bin_in_path {
  if [[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]]; then
    builtin whence -p "$1" &> /dev/null
  else  # bash:
    builtin type -P "$1" &> /dev/null
  fi
  [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && return 1
  if [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
    shift  # We've just checked the first one
    is_bin_in_path "$@"
  fi
}
```

Example usage:

```
is_bin_in_path ssh-agent ssh-add && setup_ssh_agent
```

---

### Non-solutions to avoid

This is not a short answer because the solution must correctly handle:

- Functions
- Aliases
- Builtin commands
- Reserved words

Examples which **fail** with plain `type` (note the token after `type` changes):

```
$ alias foo=ls
$ type foo && echo "in path" || echo "not in path"
foo is aliased to `ls'
in path

$ type type && echo "in path" || echo "not in path"
type is a shell builtin
in path

$ type if && echo "in path" || echo "not in path"
if is a shell keyword
in path
```

Note that in `bash`, `which` is *not* a shell builtin (it is in `zsh`):

```
$ PATH=/bin
$ builtin type which
which is /bin/which
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/5353461) says why to avoid using `which`:

> Avoid `which`.  Not only is it an external process you're launching for doing very little (meaning builtins like `hash`, `type` or `command` are way cheaper), you can also rely on the builtins to actually do what you want, while the effects of external commands can easily vary from system to system.

> Why care?

> - Many operating systems have a `which` that **doesn't even set an exit status**, meaning the `if which foo` won't even work there and will **always** report that `foo` exists, even if it doesn't (note that some POSIX shells appear to do this for `hash` too).

- Many operating systems make `which` do custom and evil stuff like change the output or even hook into the package manager.

#### In this case, also avoid `command -v`

The answer I just quoted from suggests using `command -v`, however this doesn't apply to the current "is the executable in `$PATH`?" scenario: it will *fail* in exactly the ways I've illustrated with plain `type` above.

---

### Correct solutions

In `bash` we need to use `type -P`:

> ```
>   -P        force a PATH search for each NAME, even if it is an alias,
> ```

```
            builtin, or function, and returns the name of the disk file
            that would be executed
```

In `zsh` we need to use `whence -p`:

> ```
>    -p     Do  a  path  search  for  name  even  if  it is an alias,
> ```

```
          reserved word, shell function or builtin.
```

Comment: "It works correctly for aliases and functions" - not true. Try this in Bash: `alias foo=ls; is_bin_in_path foo && echo "in path" || echo "not in path"`.

Comment: Good catch, @EugeneYarmash. Updated and fixed.

Comment: `type -P` is a bashism, and will cause problems when used from scripts where you can't guarantee that the shell is bash --- for example, makefiles with `$(shell)`.

Comment: @David Given, the question is tagged bash....

Comment: @TomHale So it is --- my bad!

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `command` builtin, which is POSIX compatible:

```
if [ -x "$(command -v "$cmd")" ]; then
    echo "$cmd is in \$PATH"
fi
```

The executable check is needed because `command -v` detects functions and aliases as well as executables.

In Bash, you can also use `type` with the `-P` option, which forces a `PATH` search:

```
if type -P "$cmd" &>/dev/null; then
    echo "$cmd is in \$PATH"
fi
```

As already mentioned in the comments, avoid `which` as it requires launching an external process and might give you incorrect output in [some cases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86029/903).

Comment: Its better then `which` as is doesnt throw an error

Answer (score 1):

if command -v foo ; then foo ; else echo "foo unavailable" ; fi

Comment: This will break with functions or aliases. [This answer works, in both `bash` and `zsh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53798785/5353461)

Comment: Can you add some more explanation to that snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`which`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which)

```
$ which myprogram
```

Comment: `which ` is indeed, awesome =)

Comment: which should be avoided, see stackoverflow.com/a/677212

Answer (score 0):

We can define a function for checking whether as executable exists by using `which`:

```bash
function is_executable() {
    which "$@" &> /dev/null
}
```

The function is called just like you would call an executable. `"$@"` ensures that `which` gets exactly the same arguments as are given to the function.

`&> /dev/null` ensures that whatever is written to stdout or stderr by `which` is redirected to the null device (which is a special device which discards the information written to it) and not written to stdout or stderr by the function.

Since the function doesn't explicitly return with an return code, when it does return, the exit code of the latest executed executable—which in this case is `which`—will be the return code of the function. `which` will exit with a code that indicates success if it is able to find the executable specified by the argument to the function, otherwise with an exit code that indicates failure. This behavior will automatically be replicated by `is_executable`.

We can then use that function to conditionally do something:

```bash
if is_executable name_of_executable; then
    echo "name_of_executable was found"
else
    echo "name_of_executable was NOT found"
fi
```

Here, [`if`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) executes the command(s) written between it and `then`—which in our case is `is_executable name_of_executable`—and chooses the branch to execute based on the return code of the command(s).

Alternatively, we can skip defining the function and use `which` directly in the `if`-statement:

```bash
if which name_of_executable &> /dev/null; then
    echo "name_of_executable was found"
else
    echo "name_of_executable was NOT found"
fi
```

However, I think this makes the code slightly less readable.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Sure, I can put in some comments. What is "Low Qualtiy posts in SO"?

Comment: these are the review queues 3rd one from left menu. if they feel answer has minimal information and not explained then it will go to review queue. to close. most commonly code only answers will go. in your case it is.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Is this good?

Comment: should NOT use which in a bash shell.  see : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then/86029#86029